# What's the difference between EWX_POWEROFF & EWX_SHUTDOWN?

Tags: c#, windows

I'm just after clarification as the the difference between `EWX_SHUTDOWN` and `EWX_POWEROFF`.

Is it that `EWX_SHUTDOWN` takes the system to a point where it can be **manually** switched off, and `EWX_POWEROFF` takes it to that same point, but also powers off the system?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376868.aspx) says as much, yes.

Comment: Cheers Frederic, I have seen that, was just making sure my understanding was correct :)

Comment: The "shut down but not powered off" state used to be common, before PCs were designed to allow the operating system to turn off the power.  There may still be edge cases where it is useful, though I can't think of any offhand.  However, services will continue to run by default, and at least some parts of the operating system API are still available, so it is theoretically possible to have the operating system shut down but for the computer to still be doing something useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, that is the difference, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you :)
(I have to wait another 5mins before I can accept as answer.)